# Unique occurrence of period within the list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I'm using the textwrap module to split my string into a list with width = 40. Then, I'm trying to iterate through the list and after every 2nd period, type "We hit second period" and then reset the counting. The problem I think I'm having is that if there is multiple periods within the list, my iteration doesn't work. After running the following code I get "We hit second period" twice, instead of 3 times, as we have 6 periods within the list.

```
import textwrap
text = "We are having a long, long long very long sentence here. Just trying to test if it works. We are trying to test. Testing we do. All day. Long."
unique_character = textwrap.wrap(text, width=40)
x=0
for items in unique_character:
    print(items)
    items.count(".")
    if x == 0:
        x+=1
    elif x==1:
        x+=1
    elif x ==2:
        print("We hit second period")
    else:
        x=0
```

Comment: So when `x` hits 2, do you ever change its value, or does it stay 2? Think you might want to reset `x` to 0.

Comment: Just noticed that you aren't even incrementing `x` when you've found a period, might want to change that too.

Comment: use long division with `divmod(items.count('.'), 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the value `items.count(".")` returnes. I also created a solution, that doesn't use it, since adding the number of . in a line would not work if we were adding 3 or more at a time.

```
import textwrap
text = "We are having a long, long long very long sentence here. Just trying to test if it works. We are trying to test. Testing we do. All day. Long."
unique_character = textwrap.wrap(text, width=40)
period_count = 0
for items in unique_character:
    print(items)
    for l in items:
        if l == ".":
            period_count += 1
            if period_count % 2 == 0 and period_count:
                print("We hit second period")
```

Comment: is there a way to accomplish this with only one for loop? @Nejc

Comment: I don't thik so, but even if you use count funcion, that is still just a loop, so the performance doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually save the result of `items.count` to a variable, and add it to the accumulator.

```
import textwrap
text = "We are having a long, long long very long sentence here. Just trying to test if it works. We are trying to test. Testing we do. All day. Long."
unique_character = textwrap.wrap(text, width=40)
accumDots = 0
for line in unique_character:
    print(line)
    dots = line.count(".")
    if accumDots + dots >= 2:
        print("We hit second period")
        accumDots = 0
    else:
        accumDots += dots
```

Comment: This solution would not work if there were 3 or more . in 1 line, like there are in the last line of the given example. For that reason, this code still prints "We hit second period" only twice.

Comment: @Nejc I believe *reset after every 2nd period* means that it triggers on 3 periods as well (as the code shows). Depends on how the OP meant this.

Comment: Since his complaint was " I get "We hit second period" twice, instead of 3 times" I believe he meant it the same way I did.

Comment: I'm not sure what he actually meant, but I'll leave my answer as is for now since the acceptance criteria is ambiguous.

Comment: @Fractalism I want for it to become 0 after 2nd period if that helps.